# Cannot acces methods from angular service

Tags: angular

Hi im trying to access a method from my service but i m geting this error message. What am i missing here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you save all files? Stop the development server and start it again?

Comment: yes, i don t know what i did wrong

Comment: Do you have HttpClientModule imported?

Comment: yes, i did.. i will try a new project..

Comment: I have created this project for you reference:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-ra5wy1

Comment: thank you very much it works now!

Comment: No problem, let me add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing import for `HttpClientModule`.

```
...
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [ ..., HttpClientModule ],
  ...
})
```